# How to make a function change the value of a variable which was previously assigned

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to make the method "add", which extends "Number" objects, edit the value of the variable it was assigned. Just like .push method.

So whenever I do (variable) 5.add(2) and I log it into console it displays 7 instead of the variable's original value.

I see **.push** method change's the variable's value,
EX:

```js
let i = ['Hey'];
i.push('Hiya');
console.log(i); // Displays ['Hey', 'Hiya']
```

This is what I have:

```js
Number.prototype.add = function(number) { // Creating the method.

    if (typeof(number) == 'string') number = Number(number);
    if (typeof(number) == 'object') return 'ERROR - You introduced an object.';

    let finalNumber = this.valueOf() + number;
    return finalNumber;
}

let ourNumber = 5; // The variable's value is a Number.
ourNumber.add(3) // Makes the number be 5 + 3 (8) now.

// EXPECTED OUTPUT
console.log(ourNumber); // This is expected to display 8 on console.

// REAL OUTPUT
console.log(ourNumber); // It displays 5 instead of 8, which is I want it to do.
```

I expect the output of 8, but instead I get the original variable's value, which is 5.

Comment: @ShubhamSharma replacing the only **this** with **this.valueOf** changes nothing.

Comment: Numbers are immutable in javascript. You can return a new number and assign the return value to `ourNumber`, but you can't change the value internally.

Comment: Welcome to SO! My two cents: even if this could be done, that doesn't mean it should be done.

Comment: @MarkMeyer I mean to change the value stored in the variable, from the original to the new one.

Comment: You can do it with `valueOf` by using it like a setter.